# Getting Django and Subversion to work together on Dreamhost

Tags: django, svn, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

Does anyone know how to get Django and Subversion to work together on Dreamhost?

I've been following this tutorial to install Django (which uses Passenger WSGI):
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django

After I got Django to work, Subversion stopped working. Has anyone ran into this problem?

Comment: need more details. what doesn't work about it? also make sure the django installation didn't mess up any of your paths.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My solution for now has been to move the Subversion link to a different subdomain.

In my case, I'm only using Django for 1 subdomain in my whole domain (`dom1.myurl.com`), so I just created a `dom2.myurl.com` subdomain, and set my SVN path to use it instead.